# Interpreting the result of ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I want to understand what exactly `ContourPlot3D` is plotting here.  I wanted to check that there are no solutions $(x,y,z)$ to the equation

$$\frac{1}{a b (1 - x - y - z)}=0$$

for real-valued $a$ and $b$.

I plotted

```
With[{a = 5.31, b = -5}, 
  ContourPlot3D[1/(a b (1 - x - y - z)) == 0, 
        {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
]
```

And I got a plane:

[image]

I could've sworn there aren't any solutions to the equation.  I even confirmed it with

```
With[{a = 5.31, b = -5}, 
  FindInstance[1/(a b (1 - x - y - z)) == 0, {x, y, z}]]
```

> ```
> (* {} *)
> ```

It looks like the locus of points I'm getting is the one which makes the denominator zero *i.e.* $a b (1 - x - y - z)=0$.  So is `ContourPlot` supposed to be doing that?  Or maybe I'm making a simple mistake here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `CountourPlot3D` is plotting the region where the left hand side changes sign, i.e. goes from positive to negative. This is interpreted as a zero.

We can see this by plotting where the left hand side is negative, and noticing this plane lies on its boundary.

```
With[{a = 5.31, b = -5},
  Show[
    RegionPlot3D[
      1/(a b (1 - x - y - z)) < 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
      PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"Negative"}]
    ],
    ContourPlot3D[
      1/(a b (1 - x - y - z)) == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
      ContourStyle -> Red, 
      PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"Sign change"}]
    ]
  ]
]
```

[image]

In fact `ContourPlot3D` can also have the opposite problem, and miss features if the expression never changes sign. For example this input incorrectly produces a blank plot.

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^2 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

This can be found in the Possible Issues section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html).

### Edit

A simpler example of this issue: $1/x$ changes sign at $x = 0$ and has no zeros.

```
ContourPlot[1/x == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fundamentally this is because the `ContourPlot*` functions rely on the intermediate value theorem, which breaks down here because the function is not continuous.

Comment: @Rahul precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Take a small test:

```
With[{a = 5.31, b = -5}, 
   ContourPlot3D[
    1/(a b (1 - x - y - z)) == #, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10,
      10}, Contours -> 0, ImageSize -> 150]] & /@ {-1, 0, 1}
```

[image]

Only Null has a solution!